Custom CompositeMove issue
I have a situation where there are some mutually dependent planning entities and I need score recalculation after they are moved "as one". E.g. two tasks which are being scheduled have same start dependency, which violation brings 1hard. Thing is I can never get 0hard because first OP moves one task and recalculates score, then moves second one, etc. and never gets to the point where start is same.
I am trying to implement custom composite move but I'm stuck. I've added custom move, just like stated in documentation: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#customMoves.
And my custom factory code is here:
public class CompositeMoveFactory implements MoveListFactory<PlanningSolution> {

  @Override
  public List<? extends Move<PlanningSolution>> createMoveList(PlanningSolution planningSolution) {

    var compositeMoves = new ArrayList<CompositeMove<PlanningSolution>>();

    var tasksWithDependencies = opPlanningSolution.getTasks().stream()
        .filter(task -> task.isNewTask() && !task.getDependsOnTaskIds().isEmpty())
        .toList();

    var taskIdToTaskMap = tasksWithDependencies.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(OPTask::getId, Function.identity()));

    for (var task : tasksWithDependencies) {

      for (var dependsOnTaskId : task.getDependsOnTaskIds()) {

        var dependsOnTask = taskIdToTaskMap.get(dependsOnTaskId);

        for (var it = opPlanningSolution.createDateTime().createOriginalIterator();
            it.hasNext(); ) {

          LocalDateTime newStartTime = it.next();

          for (Resource newResource : planningSolution.getResources()) {

            var taskMove = new ChangeStartTimeAndResourceMove(task, newStartTime, newResource);
            var dependsOnTaskMove = new ChangeStartTimeAndResourceMove(dependsOnTask, newStartTime,
                newResource);

            var compositeMove = (CompositeMove<PlanningSolution>) CompositeMove.buildMove(
                taskMove, dependsOnTaskMove);

            compositeMoves.add(compositeMove);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return compositeMoves;
  }
}

Is this code for custom factory good for what I'm trying to achieve?
